# What do you call the legal document(s) that Iran signed to alleviate concerns of nuclear proliferation?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the legal documents that Iran signed to alleviate concerns of nuclear proliferation? I am asking, because I am pretty sure there are many similar documents and they carry different legal implications. I would like to know the name of the one Iran signed under Obama. I am asking what type of document it is, not the name of the document itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referred to as a treaty, or a "[(Nuclear) Non-Proliferation Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons)"